# Action bar option action

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

Before Clicking:

[image: Before Clicking]

After Clicking:

[image: After clicking]

I am having an issue with my code where clicking on an actionbar action will bring up the title of the action. If you then click on the title that is how you get to the onclick listener. Very strange... I know it is hard to tell without code but I am away and will post it soon. Just wanted to ask around to see if anyone has experienced similar.

ActionBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/hello1"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

onClickListener:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            onCreateDialog();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onCreateDialog() {
    String[] string= new String[]{"Add to Calendar", "Share"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Options")
            .setItems(string, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:...................}
```

Comment: If you are going to post the question, post it with the code. Otherwise, the likely hood of you getting your answer is low.

Comment: So when you click the `Setting` menu item in the action bar, you are showing an alert dialog. What is your issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by extending the activity to appcompatactivity instead of activity. Weird bug. Then it didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior for the way you have the menu setup currently.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/hello1"
    app:showAsAction="never"/> <!-- Don't show this action until the overflow menu is shown -->
```

With the `showAsAction` set to `never`, the action is not shown until the overflow menu is shown. The available options for `showAsAction` are:

```
["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]
```

In your case, because you only have one menu item, you can use `always`.

Refer to the [menu resource documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) for more info.

You should be able to preview this in Android Studio (see screenshot below)

[image: Android Studio Preview]

Comment: I had it set to always earlier and it had the same behavior. However, I will attempt this solution.

Comment: It is possible that your string is too long for it to fit in the app bar. You can either shorten it or use an icon as well. If you provide an icon, the icon is shown instead unless there is space for the text as well

Comment: No dice, I also shortened to just "options".

Comment: Try `always|withText`

Comment: I tested this quick and was able to get it to work. I would suggest that you preview this in Android Studio to get the correct configuration.